# How to make Voice0ver read dates correctly

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, voiceover

> NOTE: using Chrome on Mac with VoiceOver

If the date is "September 16th 2016", what VoiceOver reads is "September One Six T H Two Zero One Six". Is there any way to make it read correctly as "September Sixteenth Two Thousand and Sixteen".
[code pen link](http://codepen.io/anilnamde/pen/RGVNLX)

```
<div tabindex="0" aria-label="September 16th 2016">16</div>
```

One solution could to to change the `aria-label` attribute to hold "September Sixteenth Two Thousand and Sixteen" text, but is there any library which can read it correctly ?

Comment: VoiceOver users typically do not use Chrome, they use Safari. That being said, what you may consider as incorrect may be perfectly fine to a VO user and changing it can make it more difficult for users. Find some VO users and get their feedback first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you do not try to change the behavior.

You are assuming that VoiceOver users will struggle with this. It is more likely that VoiceOver users are familiar with this from all the other sites they visit that announce dates like this.

If anything, consider getting rid of the ordinal indicator (the "th," "rd," "nd," etc). Maybe allow it to display visually, but hide it from screen readers using `aria-hidden`.

Also, VoiceOver users typically do not use Chrome, they use Safari.

I also suggest you find some VoiceOver users and get their feedback.

Answer (score 1):

SR don't have a library, to be compliant you should be semantic and what you see is what SR announce, you can use the aria-label with the full text "September Sixteenth Two Thousand and Sixteen" and is totally correct with A11Y standars. Tabindex are not a best practice for a11y.

Answer (score 0):

Either use `aria-label` and word it the way you want it read, or, be aware that this is a VoiceOver (VO) preference (a setting).

For example. If you want your "September 16th, 2016" to be read as expected, then do the following.

1. Start VoiceOver
2. Hold `VO+V` (control + option + V)
3. This gives you the Verbosity Rotor. Press the right arrow to go through the panels until you reach "numbers"
4. Change it to "words"

Now try reading your text again. It should read as expected.

Sometimes, it's a screen-reader preference.